# Bring about peace OR bring peace?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a college dormitory application and one of the questions was "what is my characteristics?" And I said I am flexible with people, and that I have never gotten in any arguments with people. 
And for my last sentence, I wanted to say

"I surely will bring about peace to this dormitory"

As to how I can contribute to this dorm. 
Is this grammatically correct to say "bring about peace"??

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume as you are doing that the dormitory is not at peace now :)

You must choose between "bring about peace *in* the dormitory" or "bring peace *to* the dormitory".  They cannot be combined as you are doing because the prepositions **about** and **to** express opposite spatial/locative ideas. These locative meanings are present even though the collocations have acquired an abstract meaning.

**bring about peace** is a variant of **bring peace about**. The meaning doesn't change when the position of **about** changes.

If you *intervene* in a fight (that is, if you *come between* the fighters), you can **bring about** peace. You effect change *in the midst* of contention.

Just as you can spread rumors *about*, you can bring peace *about*. Compare the collocation "around and about".

If you **bring peace to** a place, there is no sense that peace is effected in the midst of the contention, as there is with "bring about peace" or "bring peace about".  The preposition **to** at its very core expresses the idea of 'in the direction of a destination, towards'.

So you bring about peace **in** a place, or bring peace **to** a place.